# Unrecognized `swift_version` key

Tags: swift, cocoapods, podspec

I can’t push a new version of my pod to the CocoaPods specs repository.

Running `pod trunk push MyPod.podspec` results in the following error:

```
[!] The Pod Specification did not pass validation.
The following validation failed:
- Warnings: Unrecognized `swift_version` key.
```

Here’s my podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|

  spec.name = "MyPod"
  spec.version = "0.1.1"
  spec.summary = "[REDACTED]"
  spec.homepage = "[REDACTED]"
  spec.license = "Apache License, version 2"
  spec.author = "[REDACTED]"
  spec.social_media_url = "[REDACTED]"
  spec.module_name = "MyPod"
  spec.swift_version = "5.0"
  spec.platform = :ios, "8.0"
  spec.source = { :git => "https://github.com/[REDACTED].git", :tag => "v#{spec.version}" }
  spec.source_files = "MyPod/**/*.{h,m,swift}"

end
```

What am I doing wrong?

I first noticed these errors **before** updating to Swift 5 and Xcode 10.2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems to be a server-side bug. It’s been reported [on GitHub](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8635).

However, since it’s a warning, not an error (despite it’s in red font color, which is confusing), it can be ignored with the `--allow-warnings` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Summary, to update a pod:

Update the version and the tag in podspec beforehand
Commit, push code to git
Create new tag with the current code, make sure it's the same tag as the one in podspec

git tag 0.1.1

git push origin 0.1.1
Call pod spec lint to check and pod trunk push to update it on repo master list

pod lib lint YourSDK.podspec

pod trunk push YourSDK.podspec
It appears that your podfile is using the tag v0.1.1, however the tag in your repository is 0.1.1 without the v. This would also cause linting to fail.

Comment: No, it’s not the case: “v” in version number is present both in the podspec and in the repo.
Besides, the lint command says the pod passed validation; however, pushing to the trunk fails.

Comment: that's warning. so when you trunk push, allow warnings: 


pod trunk push MyPod.podspec --allow-warnings

hope to help you

Comment: Ah, it’s a warning, indeed. Thank you @AbbasTorabi. I was confused by the red font color, and though it was an error which can’t be ignored by passing the `--allow-warnings` argument.